# p values and confidence intervals

Tags: confidence-interval, reporting

I have run partial correlations with bootstrapping to get confidence intervals. In my SPSS output I am getting significant p values with CI's that include 0 (for example: *r* = -.58, 95% CI [-.886, .054], *p* = 0.007).

I am reporting/discussing detection of effect size, not *p* values, so even though these are moderate to large effect sizes, do I not discuss them?

Comment: How’d you get the p-value?

Comment: p value were take directly from SPSS partial correlation tables/output